# How can i Convert CMD to Entrypoint instruction in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-run, docker-entrypoint

My cmd instruction in dockerfile is:

```
CMD /etc/init.d/ssh start && su - gpadmin bash -c /home/gpadmin/entrypoint.sh && tail -f /dev/null
```

I want to convert it to ENTRYPOINT instruction. My entrypoint script file is entrypoint.sh

I want to enter the entrypoint script with gpadmin user and also i want the container to stay alive with docker run command that is why i am using tail -f /dev/null command

Comment: A Docker container generally wraps a process.  What should that process be?  (Why is it important to have a container blocking on a read forever?)  Is there any particular reason you want the harder-to-override `ENTRYPOINT` over `CMD`?  What have you already tried, and what issue are you running into?

Comment: (In the abstract I'd probably recommend `USER gpadmin`, `CMD entrypoint.sh` launching a foreground process, and avoiding the ssh daemon and `tail` process.)